# require('react') vs require('React')

Tags: gulp, node-modules, require

The following code in external node_modules is not working:

`var _react = require('react');`

But:

`var _react = require('React');`

works. Now I have a problem that in some node_modules it is required with 'react', and then I get this error:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'`

I am using gulp as build tool.

What can I do so that both requires will work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 'React' added in your package.json ?

If not, add: "react": "17.0.2" (or another React version)

Try running the command:

```
npm install
```

And try again

Comment: I have it, and if the call is in the extern node_modules with Capital Letter it works

Answer (score -1):

Require is not a React api. Try this syntax:

```
import React from 'react'
```

Comment: Read it again, it is in some node_modules where require('React') is working but not require('react'), and I could change the code in all node_modules where this appears but that cant be the solution.